# Split a string according to the sentence phrases contained in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to split a sentence according to the phrases that coincide with the list.
E.g:

```
sentence = "the world is too big"
list = ["too big", "too small", "the world", "too many"]
```

If the sentence contains a phrase that belongs to the list, the decomposition result it wants to see is:

```
result = ["the world", "is", "too big"]
```

Instead of:

```
result = ["the", "world", "is", "too", "big"]
```

Thank you so much

Comment: just a sidenote, never use the word `list` to define variables as you're shadowing the inbuilt `list` with that. Same goes for `dict`, `str`, `int`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sentence = "the world is too big"
list = ["too big", "too small", "the world", "too many"]
for data in list:
  if data in sentence:
   sentence = sentence.replace(data, data.replace(' ', '..............'))
sentence = sentence.split(' ')
for i in range(len(sentence)):
 if '..............' in sentence[i]:
  sentence[i] = sentence[i].replace('..............', ' ')
print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.split`:

```
import re

s = "the world is too big"
l = ["too big", "too small", "the world", "too many"]
r = fr"\s*({'|'.join(l)})\s*"
```

```
>>> re.split(r, s)[1:-1]
['the world', 'is', 'too big']

>>> r
'\\s*(too big|too small|the world|too many)\\s*'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but after I changed a sentence, the result displayed is not that all words except the phrases in the list are broken down one by one. For example: when s = "I think the world is not too big", the result is hoped to be ['I','think','the world','is','not','too big'], not ['the world', 'is not', 'too big'].